# Bounding box of wrapped text

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to draw a rectangle around a QML `Text` object that is using word wrapping. [`TextMetrics`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textmetrics.html) seems like it would be ideal, but it does not appear to support wrapped text.

How can I measure how text is laid out in a `Text` object? Must I match the wrapping logic and manually calculate the offsets using `TextMetrics` and [`FontMetrics`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-fontmetrics.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`contentWidth`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#contentWidth-prop) and [`contentHeight`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#contentHeight-prop):

```
Text {
    text: "..."
    wrapMode: Text.Wrap

    Rectangle {
        border.color: "red"
        color: "transparent"
        width: parent.contentWidth
        height: parent.contentHeight
    }
}
```

Comment: If I have `Text { width:400; height:400; wrapMode:Text.WordWrap; text:"hi" }` the rectangle is going to be a 400x400 square, instead of fitting just to the words.

Comment: You can use [contentWidth](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#contentWidth-prop) and [contentHeight](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#contentHeight-prop).