# Locating edge of last line of wrapped text

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a QML `Text` object with constrained width and wrapping lines:

[image]

```qml
Text {
    width:200; height:200; wrapMode:Text.WordWrap
    text:"It's the end of the world as we know it, and I feel fine."
    Rectangle {
        width:parent.contentWidth;
        height:parent.contentHeight;
        border.color:'red'; color:'transparent'
    }
}
```

I would like to calculate where the final period is (or just to the right of it). I tried using `TextMetrics`, but it does not support wrapping (and in any case would just give me the overall bounding box). I tried using [`onLineLaidOut`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#lineLaidOut-signal) to read the width of the last line, but the width of all lines is the same as the width of the overall `Text` object.

How can I find the X,Y coordinates of the bottom right corner of that last line?

---

**Edit**: as requested, here's a test case showing that the `lineLaidOut` signal cannot be used to measure the `width` actually used:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id:app; visible:true; width:300; height:300
    property string message: "It's the end of the world as we know it, and I feel fine."
    Text {
        id:words; x:10; y:10
        width:150; height:150; wrapMode:Text.WordWrap
        onLineLaidOut: console.log((line.number+1)+"/"+lineCount,line.width)
        Rectangle {
            width:parent.contentWidth; height:parent.contentHeight;
            border.color:'red'; color:'transparent'
        }
    }
    Timer {
        property int chars:0
        interval:200; running:true; repeat:true
        onTriggered: words.text=message.substring(0,++chars);
    }
}
```

The output of this shows that `line.width` is always the full width of the text object, even before the first line is fully filled:

```
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 1/1 150
qml: 2/1 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 1/2 150
qml: 2/2 150
qml: 3/2 150
qml: 1/3 150
qml: 2/3 150
qml: 3/3 150
qml: 1/3 150
qml: 2/3 150
qml: 3/3 150
qml: 1/3 150
qml: 2/3 150
qml: 3/3 150
qml: 1/3 150
qml: 2/3 150
qml: 3/3 150
```

Comment: Related question: [Bounding box of wrapped text](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39086999/405017)

Comment: Please edit the question to provide a test case that uses `onLineLaidOut`. And then submit it as a Qt bug if it indeed doesn't work as it should. It's meant to work the way you expect it to, but let's see the code first.

Comment: @KubaOber Interesting, I was unsure if the `width` should be usable in this way. I've edited with a test case.

Comment: FWIW, I have filed a bug (titled ["lineLaidOut line.width always full width"](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55445)); we'll see if this is in fact a bug. Either way, I still need a workaround (perhaps using FontMetrics and manually wrapping the text myself :/).

Answer (score 0):

I found kinda crazy solution, but it worked for me.

```
function findEndOfWrappedText(label) {
    var x = 0
    var y = 0
    var fakeLink = "<a href='f'>█</a>"

    var finder = function(line) {
        if (line.number !== label.lineCount - 1)
            return

        for (var i = 0; i < label.width; ++i) {
            if (label.linkAt(line.x + i, line.y + (line.height / 2))) {
                x = line.x + i
                y = line.y
                break
            }
        }
    }

    label.lineLaidOut.connect(finder)
    label.text = label.text + fakeLink
    label.lineLaidOut.disconnect(finder)
    label.text = label.text.substring(0, label.text.length - fakeLink.length)
    return Qt.point(x,y)
}
```

So all you need to do is to use this function, like:

```
Text {
    id: label
    ...

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var point = findEndOfWrappedText(label)
        ...
    }
}
```

If you have better solution, feel free to fix my idea :)